# Is it possible to implement alle logical functions only with XNOR and AND-gates??(Hardware)

Tags: hardware, computer-science, logical-operators, boolean-logic

> i have to show, that it is possible to implement all logical functions
>   only with XNOR and AND-gates, if you take an extra argument, which is
>   wired to the logical wire(0 or 1).

I think with the "extra argument" they refer to, is a negation.

Sorry for asking to help you with my exercise sheet, but thats the only thing i dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got negation you can use:

```
P NOR Q <-> P XNOR Q AND NOT P
```

It should be granted as known, that you can implement all with NOR.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate